# FreeBSD: Does Install media include I2C modules?

Tags: freebsd, keyboard, macintosh, hardware-compatibility

When I booted a memstick image of FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE on my Apple Macbook, the keyboard was not recognised post-boot. I think this is because the keyboard is I2C-based, as plugging a USB keyboard in worked fine. Is there an I2C module shipped with the default images?

Comment: Not a FreeBSD user, but there's a [man page for i2c](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=i2c), so it'd seem reasonable.

Comment: additional reference: https://vzaigrin.wordpress.com/2014/04/28/working-with-i2c-in-freebsd-on-raspberry-pi/ "It appeared in FreeBSD-10.0-STABLE"